# Sorting strings using Counting Sort in O(n), where n is the total number of characters in all the strings

Tags: algorithms, sorting

Suppose, you are given an array of strings of different lengths, but the total number of characters over all the strings is *n*. Describe an algorithm using **Counting Sort** to sort the strings in alphabetic order (eg. algorithm < cs < hello) in **O(n)** time.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question?

Comment: The common assessment of the time required by *Counting Sort* has a second parameter in addition to some measure $n$ of the input. Please show how far you got.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the general idea:

1. Sort all the strings according to their first character (refer to each string using an index to save time).
2. Partition the strings according to their first character, and run recursively on each part (deleting in your mind the first character).

I'll let you work out the details.

Comment: I am thinking the same. But will it be still in O(n) ?

Comment: I think so. The complexity of the zeroth level of the recursion tree is the number of first characters. The complexity of the first level of the recursion tree is the number of second characters. And so on.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: The crux of *Counting Sort* is its dependence on "alphabet" size, say $S: |\Sigma|$. With "single letter strings", this should amount to $O(n+S)$, with two strings of length $n/2$, I see $O(nS)$

Comment: Alphabet is constant.

Comment: If you consider a _large_ alphabet (like Unicode code points) or an infinite alphabet (Unicode extended grapheme clusters), you can split characters into bytes and you can sort in O(n), where n is the number of bytes.